# Installing Ubuntu / Windows to two separate hard drives

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bootloader

So I have installed Ubuntu to a 1 TB hard drive.(I have a laptop)
I want to install Windows 7 to another 500 Gb hard drive and be able to switch out between the two hard drives. Is this possible? Will this cause a fuss with GRUB / Windows bootloader? Does having only one HDD slot in my laptop affect this? Help appreciated.

Comment: is this other hard drive a usb external or will you actually be swapping the internal drive with this other one?

Comment: I will be swapping the internal hard drive out.

Comment: @EpicCode I wouldn't be swapping drives in my laptop 1 TB is enough for both OSs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the other hard drive and install Windows like you normally would. Then you can swap them with no issue.

One thing you might see is the internal system clock will be incorrect when you go back to Windows, because Linux uses GMT while Windows uses your local time zone. Windows can auto update the clock when its online but it's something you will have to look out for. [Here is a registry edit you can do in Windows to fix this.](http://lifehacker.com/5742148/fix-windows-clock-issues-when-dual-booting-with-os-x)

Comment: OK! Thank you! Just wanted clarification before installing Windows.

Comment: Is there any chance that installing the two OSes in different boot modes (EFI and legacy) would cause any problems?

Comment: yes make sure to keep the same boot modes for both

Comment: If you don't see Windows as a GRUB boot option then ~> After installing Windows to the 2nd HDD, you may need to possibly use `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @David-yourfriend Windows shouldn't be listed as a boot option because the two HDDs won't both be installed at the same time.